# Git push failing due to company proxy certificate being changed

Tags: git, curl, https, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04

Recently, the certificates for the company proxy was changed. Ever since, I have been facing problems using git. When I try to do a `git push` , I get the following error:

```
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: The Diffie-Hellman prime sent by the server is not acceptable (not long enough). while accessing https://github.com/me/myproj.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I could just switch to pushing using HTTP or switching off sslVerify by doing `git config --global http.sslVerify false` but they insist I use ***only*** HTTPS.

I have a *.cer* certificate file which I've been asked to install system wide in my Ubuntu desktop (Ubuntu 12.04) but I have not been able to find a way to do it. Please help !

Here is the *curl* logs I obtained after performing `export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`:

```
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy proxy.mycompany.com port 5150 (#0)
*   Trying 10.226.xx.yyy... * Connected to proxy.mycompany.com (10.226.xx.yyy) port 5150 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'me'
> CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com:443
Proxy-Authorization: Basic MjQABCD3Og==
User-Agent: git/1.7.9.5
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2012 11:45:37 GMT
< Age: 0
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Via: 1.0 MYCOMPANYSERVER.MYCOMPANY.COM
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* found 1 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: The Diffie-Hellman prime sent by the server is not acceptable (not long enough).
* Closing connection #0
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy proxy.mycompany.com port 5150 (#0)
*   Trying 10.226.xx.yyy... * Connected to proxy.mycompany.com (10.226.xx.yyy) port 5150 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to github.com:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'me'
> CONNECT github.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com:443
Proxy-Authorization: Basic MjQABCD3Og==
User-Agent: git/1.7.9.5
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2012 11:45:37 GMT
< Age: 0
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Via: 1.0 MYCOMPANYSERVER.MYCOMPANY.COM
< 
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* found 1 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: The Diffie-Hellman prime sent by the server is not acceptable (not long enough).
* Closing connection #0
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: The Diffie-Hellman prime sent by the server is not acceptable (not long enough). while accessing https://github.com/me/myproject.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is using `/etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt` as the certificate.

You can try and copy the certificate file in your possession under `/etc/ssl/certs/` and then give the command `c_rehash .` (watch for the dot!) inside that directory, as the root user.